# iOS extension and Test Flight

Tags: ios

I am trying to add a Share Extension to my iOS App and ever since I have added it I get this error message when I try to install it from test flight

[image: Message Fro9m Test Flight]

I have noted that when I look at the entitlements in iTunes Connect I see this

xxxxx extension
application-identifier: ShareExtension
get-task-allow: false
com.apple.developer.team-identifier: DB2Jxxxxx
com.apple.security.application-groups: ( "xxxx" )
xxxx main app
application-identifier: xxxxxx
get-task-allow: false
beta-reports-active: true
com.apple.developer.team-identifier: DB2Jxxxxx
com.apple.security.application-groups: ( "xxxx" )

and the extension does not have the beta-reports-active: true entitlement is that the issue and how do I fix it

Regards Christian Stœr Andersen

Comment: you share extension bundle identifier should be your developer prefix.ShareExtension and you have to see groups added in your extension bundle id after that regenerate new profile.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Extension was signed with a with a adhoc profile not the store profile

Comment: thats not a solution, Adhoc profile can not use for distribution.